# How to select best match in JMeter using regular expression?

Tags: jmeter

Created a JMeter regular expression and getting 4 matches, i need only value "441157" and I'm unable to get it.

```
Jmeter RegEx- "TimeSeriesId":(\b[0-9]+\b)`enter code here`

Match count: 4
Match[1][0]="TimeSeriesId":441157`enter code here`
Match[1][1]=441157`enter code here`
Match[2][0]="TimeSeriesId":441157`enter code here`
Match[2][1]=441157`enter code here`
Match[3][0]="TimeSeriesId":441157`enter code here`
Match[3][1]=441157`enter code here`
Match[4][0]="TimeSeriesId":441157`enter code here`
Match[4][1]=441157`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try amending your regular expression to look like:

```
"TimeSeriesId":(\d+)`enter code here`
```

It should give you one match only:

[image: JMteter Regular Expression Extractor]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl5 Regular Expression Syntax](https://mythryl.org/my-Perl5_Regular_Expression_Syntax.html)